# Where can I find job listings for companies that use ethereum and are hiring developers that they'll need to train?

Tags: dapp-development

Ethereum is very interesting. I see its potential, but right now I cannot figure out what useful app/service I could implement on my own with my current very limited skills.

It almost reminds me of when 10 years ago I started to learn programming in C++. After a while, I learned how to program, but it was very difficult for me to find any useful applications for my skills.

So, maybe there are already companies which would like to hire some ethereum newbies, to build together great new services. I would like to know where I can find companies that 1) already use ethereum as a development platform and 2) are hiring people that they're willing to train.

Comment: Welcome to ethereum stackexchange! Your question "is there a lot" is hard to answer precisely. What's a lot? I think it's probably best to delete this question and ask a new question using your last sentence - "how many companies...".

Comment: Feel free to roll back my edits if they changed the intent of your question, but I think it's a little narrower & therefore easier to answer in the SE format this way.

Answer (score 7):

I think it is a good and valid question. There are not many jobs advertised currently, but there will definitely be more. There is a dedicated Ethereum jobs website here:
http://jobs.ethercasts.com

Many developers take a path of starting an open-source project based on Ethereum, getting visibility in the community. Something like this is a great way of landing a good job when they start to appear.

Answer (score 1):

In the past few months, there has been an explosion of jobs in crypto space. https://cryptojobslist.com/ seems to list a lot of top cryptocurrency jobs.

Typical sites like https://angel.co/ might also be useful.

Comment: refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) formatting a post well.